# Animation issue with UITableView and UIView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation

I am displaying data in UITableView, when the data is being loaded I show a UIView with wait message and when the is loaded in the table View, I remove the UIView using animation

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
if(viewTemp !=nil)
{
    [viewTemp removeFromSuperview];
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But I am facing issue while the animation is being shown the some of the rows of the table view are not shown unit the animation is over.

Can somebody tell me how to fix it.

Thanks
Ashwani

Comment: Are you loading the data on a worker thread?

Comment: Actually I m getting using a async web service call and then parsing the XML data, when the required data is obtained then i call this code. That is where I m seeing table view with less rows until the transition is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of animating the view to disappear, just set its color to `[UIColor clearColor]` to make it transparent.

Comment: Thanks Alex, 

But what I need to show that the view should disappear in a curl up way after the data is loaded in Table view.